# Loadrunner HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: performance, testing, loadrunner

I try to make a login on facebook with Loadrunner Script, but I get always this:

```
vuser_init.c(41): Continuing after Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500(Internal Server Error) for "https://www.facebook.com/".
```

This is my request Script (Function):

```
web_submit_data("login.php", 
    "Action=https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "Resource=0",
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://www.facebook.com/", 
    "Snapshot=t30.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=lsd", "Value=AVpPvlAG", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=email", "Value={FACEBOOK_LOGIN}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=pass", "Value={FACEBOOK_PASSWORD}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=default_persistent", "Value=0", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=timezone", "Value=-60", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=lgnrnd", "Value=013117_8ain", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=lgnjs", "Value=1392111088", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=locale", "Value=de_DE", ENDITEM, 
    EXTRARES, 

    LAST);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't test third parties without the express written permission of those who own, manage, and control the servers plus the commissioner of baseball.   To do otherwise is to engage in a denial of services attack.  Facebook has a very capable performance engineering team and they do not need your uncontrolled inputs onto their system

Use the sample applications for learning or any LAMP, WAMP or WISP applications installed on hardware/VMs that you own, manage and control.

The topic of "What causes a 500" and how to recover from it has been covered amply over the past two decades.  Take advantage of your research skills to uncover existing lore on this topic.

Bad Magic